# How to load a Cell value on a Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

hi! xD

I have a macro on Excel and when it is activated by a button, it will filter my table.

This is the macro:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "Maria"
End Sub
```

As you can see, the macro is filtering the table using the field 2 (name) and the value "Maria".

What i need is to load value of cell M1 instead of the fixed value "Maria".

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim filterName as String 
filterName = Cells(1,13).Value
```

`Dim` creates a variable named `filterName` of type `String`

The line `filterName = Cells(1,13).Value` means get the value of the cell located at row 1, column 13, and save that to the variable `filterName`.

Once you have this, you would want to do something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= filterName
```

Comment: Sorry but im not very familiar with excel and i really dont know how your function is working, since its completely different from mine wich was auto generated by "record macro".

Comment: thanks! one more thing, do you know how to automatic use the * wildcard? If the name is "Maria Doe" and the cell is "Maria" it wont show in filter. But if the cell is "Maria*" it will show in filter. How can i automatically add this * wildcard so the user dont have to type it?